# SQL - avoid select if there is pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to write MS SQL query for this case? If there is pair with 1 and -1 , I don't want select those entries at all.

| COL1 | COL2 | NOTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | I don't want select this entry becase is in pair with A -1 |
| A | -1 | I don't want select this entry becase is in pair with A 1 |
| A | 1 | OK to select - no pair (no -1 for this A ) |
| B | 1 | OK to select - no pair |
| C | 1 | OK to select - no pair |
| D | 1 | I don't want select this entry because is in pair with D -1 |
| D | -1 | I don't want select this entry because is in pair with D 1 |

Comment: Are there other columns aside from col1 and col2 in the table you want to select? Are 1 and -1 the only values in col2? Can there be more rows different than just one (e.g. four times 1 and two times -1) for a col1?

Comment: I'm sorry for not enough details in my question , I will try to improve next time. However Thorsten was able to place correct answer. Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand there is 1s and -1s and these are the only possible values for col2. If this is the case and there is at most one row difference, then you can just add the values up:

```
select col1, sum(col2)
from mytable
group by col1
having sum(col2) <> 0;
```

If there can be more rows different or there exist other values beside 1 and -1, then we must generate row numbers.

```
select col1, max(col2)
from
(
  select
    col1,
    col2,
    row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col2) as rn
  from mytable
) numbered
group by col1, rn
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Hello Thorsten, yes this is exactly what I meant. Sorry for question with not enough details. The second answer is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One method is aggregation.  Assuming there are only -1 and 1 and no duplicates with the same sign:

```
select col1, max(col2), col3
from t
group by col1, col3
having count(*) = 1;
```

Alternatively, you could use `not exists:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col3 = c.col3 and t2.col1 = t.col1 and
                        t2.col2 = - t.col1
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If for any value of Col1 sum of 1 and -1 is not 0,  it means that it has unpaired value.
try this:

```
select *
 from t
where col1 in 
(select col1 from t group by col1 having sum(col2) <> 0);
```